# How to send data to a csv file via php with table cell as textarea made by javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I've managed to read and display the contents of a csv file in an html table  and even managed to change cells into text-area on-click but when I try to save new data of the cells into the csv files, it does'nt work. Id like to save the new data to be save in the csv when I click the "OK" button.

[image]

my codes:

```
<?php
// configuration
$file = 'sales.csv';

// check if form has been submitted
if (isset($_POST['text']))
{
    // save the text contents
    file_put_contents($file, $_POST['text']);
}

// read the textfile
$text = file_get_contents($file);

echo "<html><body><table border='1' id='sales'>";
$f = fopen("sales.csv", "r");
while (($line = fgetcsv($f)) !== false) {
        echo "<tr>";
        foreach ($line as $cell) {
                echo "<form action='' method='post'><td width='100'>".htmlspecialchars($cell)."</td></form>";   
        }
        echo "</tr>";

}
fclose($f);
echo "</table></body></html>";

?>

<script>
let table = document.getElementById('sales');
let editingTd;
table.onclick = function(event) {
  let target = event.target.closest('.edit-cancel,.edit-ok,td');
  if (!table.contains(target)) return;
  if (target.className == 'edit-cancel') {
    finishTdEdit(editingTd.elem, false);
  } else if (target.className == 'edit-ok') {
    finishTdEdit(editingTd.elem, true);
  } else if (target.nodeName == 'TD') {
    if (editingTd) return; // already editing
    makeTdEditable(target);
  }
};
function makeTdEditable(td) {
  editingTd = {
    elem: td,
    data: td.innerHTML
  };
  td.classList.add('edit-td'); // td is in edit state, CSS also styles the area inside
  let textArea = document.createElement('textarea');
  textArea.style.width = td.clientWidth + 'px';
  textArea.style.height = td.clientHeight;
  textArea.className = 'edit-area';
  textArea.tagName = 'text';
  textArea.value = td.innerHTML;
  td.innerHTML = '';
  td.appendChild(textArea);
  textArea.focus();
  td.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeEnd",
    '<div class="edit-controls"><button type="submit" class="edit-ok">OK</button><button class="edit-cancel">CANCEL</button></div>'
  );
}
function finishTdEdit(td, isOk) {
  if (isOk) {
    td.innerHTML = td.firstChild.value;
  } else {
    td.innerHTML = editingTd.data;
  }
  td.classList.remove('edit-td');
  editingTd = null;
}
</script>
```

Comment: You are generating invalid HTML. The `FORM` should be completely inside the table cell (`td`) or the entire table should be within the form

Comment: That said - the form does nothing as there are no `input` elements - unless you add those dynamically somewhere and do you really need a new form for every table cell?

Comment: I will try your suggestion sir.

Comment: When i put the FORM inside TD ( <form method='post' action=''><td> vice versa ) sir, still no results. Huhu I also put the FORM before the table tag and still have no results. As I understand your second suggestion sir, I changed the textarea.tagName, etc. into Input.tagname, still has no luck sir.

Comment: Did you consider using `contentEditable` attribute for the `TD` rather than adding a `textarea`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not determine if what you have shown above is the entire page or pieces of code pasted together here for the question. The HTML generated using PHP is invalid as you have omitted the `head` completely and the Javascript code appears after the closing `html` tag.

I mentioned that you could perhaps use `contentEditable` so that the table-cells themselves become, in effect, input elements. I cobbled together a demo of how you might use `contentEditable` to display & edit your csv file.

As you are/were heavily relying upon Javascript there really is no need to actually use a `form` in the HTML - you can accomplish all that you are trying to do in other ways, notably AJAX.

Given a basic CSV file:

```
sales.csv

"John Vials",902,9214,927,9433,494
"Helen Crew",81,83552,93,847,855
"Ben Gunn III"," 1268",5369,4562,74,77
"Gemima Puddleduck",13,273,38,42,52
```

The script:

```
<?php
    

    error_reporting( E_ALL );
    
    $filename = __DIR__ . '/sales.csv';
    
    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' ){
        
        ob_clean();
        /*
            Save the new data back to the source csv file
        */
        if( isset( $_POST['text'] ) ){
            $json=json_decode( $_POST['text'] );
            
            // open the csv file in write mode
            $file = new SplFileObject( $filename, 'w' );
            
            // process each line
            foreach( $json as $line => $arr ) $file->fputcsv( $arr );
        }
        exit( sprintf( 'The file %s has been updated', basename( $filename ) ) );
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title></title>
        <style>
            table{background:whitesmoke;font-family:monospace;font-size:1rem}
            th{background:gray;color:white}
            [type='button']{margin:0.25rem; padding:0.25rem; display:inline-block;}
            td{background:white}
            [contenteditable]{background:rgba(0,255,0,0.1)}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        
        <table border=1 cellpadding='15px' cellspacing='5px' id='sales'>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Sales - 1</th>
                <th>Sales - 2</th>
                <th>Sales - 3</th>
                <th>Sales - 4</th>
                <th>Sales - 5</th>
            </tr>
        <?php
        
            $csv = new SplFileObject( $filename );
            $csv->setFlags( SplFileObject::READ_CSV | SplFileObject::SKIP_EMPTY | SplFileObject::DROP_NEW_LINE );
            
            foreach( $csv as $index => $row ) {
                if( !empty( $row ) ){
                    list( $name, $sale1, $sale2, $sale3, $sale4, $sale5 )=$row;
                    printf('
                        <tr class="data">
                            <td>%s</td>
                            <td>%s</td>
                            <td>%s</td>
                            <td>%s</td>
                            <td>%s</td>
                            <td>%s</td>
                        </tr>', $name, $sale1, $sale2, $sale3, $sale4, $sale5 );
                }
            }
        ?>
        </table>
        <script>
            /*
                helper to add a new button and assign the
                callback defined below - "bttnclickhandler"
            */
            const createbttn=(v)=>{
                let bttn=document.createElement('input');
                    bttn.onclick=bttnclickhandler;
                    bttn.className='edit-'+v.toLowerCase();
                    bttn.type='button';
                    bttn.value=v;
                    bttn.name=v;
                return bttn;
            };
            
            /*
                If no buttons already exist in current cell, add
            */
            const addbttn=(e,v)=>{
                if( !e.target.querySelector( 'input[type="button"][name="'+v+'"]' ) ) {
                    e.target.append( createbttn( v ) );
                }
            };
            
            
            /*
                If the "OK" button is clicked scan the entire
                table and collate text values into object that
                will be sent, via ajax, to the backend script
                and thus will be used to update the source csv.
            */
            const bttnclickhandler=function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                switch( this.value.toLowerCase() ){
                    case 'ok':
                        let tmp={};
                        // find all rows in table and add to output object
                        tbl.querySelectorAll('tr.data').forEach( ( tr, i )=>{
                            tmp[i]=[];
                            
                            // find all table-cells in current row - add text content to output object
                            tr.querySelectorAll('td').forEach( td => tmp[i].push( td.textContent ) )
                        });
                        
                        // prepare data for sending
                        let fd=new FormData();
                            fd.append('text', JSON.stringify( tmp ) );
                        
                        // send data to backend script
                        fetch( location.href, { method:'post',body:fd })
                            .then( r=>r.text() )
                            .then( text=>{
                                console.log( text );
                                removebttns(e);
                                e.target.blur();
                            });
                        
                    break;
                    case 'cancel':
                        removebttns(e);
                    break;
                }
            };
            
            
            /*
                scan the entire table and remove any/all
                buttons added in the process of making 
                "contentEditable"
            */
            const removebttns=function(e){
                tbl.querySelectorAll('[type="button"]').forEach( bttn => {
                    bttn.parentNode.removeAttribute('contenteditable');
                    bttn.parentNode.removeChild( bttn );
                });
            };
            
            
            
            /*
                Assign an event listener to the table but delegate
                control when the clicked target is a table-cell element.
                
                When clicked the table-cell is made "contentEditable"
                and 2 buttons are added.
            */
            let tbl=document.getElementById('sales');
                tbl.addEventListener('click',e=>{
                    if( e.target.tagName.toLowerCase()=='td' ){
                        e.target.contentEditable=true;
                        
                        addbttn(e,'OK');
                        addbttn(e,'Cancel');
                        
                        e.target.focus();
                    }
                })
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

[image: Output]

Comment: Good day sir. Thanks for the suggestion. I never tried contenteditable but it seems that its much easy than making a text area from cells. il try coding again using that. Thanks again sir.

Comment: Im sorry for the messy codes sir. Hahhaha

Comment: Good day sir.! Once again I'm truly so grateful to you. This is the second time you helped me with my problems.  This is what I needed sir. I would like to ask your permission to use your code sir and add some features on it sir on our SCHOOL LAN WEBSITE. I'll add you in my credits list sir. Thank you so much again sir.

Comment: glad I was able to help. By all means use the code but you probably should take precautions with data storage & presentation to ensure naughty students don't introduce javascript code etc